# Ajax code is not appending to html select statment

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have two selects, one to select the group and the other to show sub-group categories.

```
<div class="frmDronpDown">
    <div class="row">
        <label>group:</label><br/>
        <select name="country" id="country-list"  onChange="getState(this.value);">

        <?php while($x--)
        {
            echo "<option value='.$group_id[$x].'>$group_name[$x]</option>";} ?>
        </select> 
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label>Services:</label><br/>
        <select name="state" id="state-list" class="demoInputBox">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the `jQuery` function:

```
function getState(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POSt",
        url: "http://abcd/Get_Service.php",
        data:'gp_id='+val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#state-list").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

The `PHP` outputs:

```
<option value='5'>V Cut</option><option value='11'>Hair Wash Girls</option>
<option value='12'>Lakme Hair Cut</option>
```

I have tried many things but I'm still not getting the correct output.

Comment: it is in json format ?

Comment: no normal.as i wrote in php responce

Comment: is it possible for you to curl on your phpscript or use postman to show us the response from Get_Service.php

Comment: `console.log(data)` in your success function to see what do you get in **front-end**

Comment: alert what u get in data and check if it gives u the correct output. if it it does then check if u have included the required jquery.js file. Your code is correct, so just cross check

Comment: i dont think i am getting correct responce.

Comment: what does your Get_Service.php code look like?

Comment: `echo "<option value='$s_id'>$s_name</option>";` i have checked the  Get_Service.php from url ,it gives correct answer

Comment: You have to loop through the `data` and use `.append()` to add each  item to the state list.

Comment: i have not json encoded the data .the data in response is as in question.so is there a need to do it

Comment: @HalayemAnis this is wt i a getting in console.Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://Get_Service.php. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Answer (score 0):

you cannot set html property on a select box
instead of that give an id to your services div say

```
<div class="row" id="services">
    <label>Services:</label><br/>
    <select name="state" id="state-list" class="demoInputBox">
    </select>
</div>
```

and then in your php page put following html code around your output code in php file

```
<label>Services:</label><br/>
<select name="state" id="state-list" class="demoInputBox">
// Your php page output
</select>
```

and then finally in your ajax code do following changes.

```
function getState(val) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POSt",
    url: "http://abcd/Get_Service.php",
    data:'gp_id='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#services").html(data);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: didnt work.Is there a need to change data field in javascript if the type changes to get

Comment: @rohan: Please post your Get_service.php page code.

Comment: `
    echo "<label>Services:</label><br/>";
    echo "<select name='state' id='state-list' class='demoInputBox'>";
// Your php page output
   
    while($row1=$services->fetch_assoc())
    {
    //    echo "<option value=".$services_array[$j]['service_id'].">"$services_array[$j]['service_name']"</option>";
    
        $s_id=$row1['service_id'];
        $s_name=$row1['service_name'];
        echo "<option value='$s_id'>$s_name</option>";
        $i++;
    }
    echo "</select>";  `

Comment: `$group_id=$_REQUEST['group_id'];`

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://abcd/Get_Service.php. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).i am getting this in responce

Answer (score 0):

[Rohan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4017139/rohan) said in his comment : 
"***Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at Get_Service.php. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)***."
That because you try to make an Ajax Request different than the original domain: Host and/or Port are different

Try with this JavaScript function :

```
function getState(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type       : "POSt",
        url        : "http://abcd/Get_Service.php",
        data       : "gp_id=" + val,
        dataType   : "jsonp",
        crossDomain: true,        
        success    : function(data){
            $("#state-list").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getState(val) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POSt",
        url: "http://abcd/Get_Service.php",
        data:'gp_id='+val,
        success: function(data){
        document.getElementById("state-list").innerHTML=data;
        }
    });
}
```

try to override innerHTML of id state-list